AMOVA with poppr - pegas implementation - interpretation results + compute % variance
I tried running poppr:amova with dist= NULL (Euclidean distance calculated by the function itself) and either the pegas implementation (see code below).
My dataset contains 3000 SNPs and my hierarchical structure consists of 2 clusters, and populations within each clusters. So I have 3 levels: variance among clusters, variance among populations within clusters and variance among individuals (within populations or in general across the whole sample??).
Running poppr::amova with pegas implementation
Eucl_popprAMOVAres = poppr::poppr.amova(
 myGenlight,
    hier = ~clusters/pop,
    clonecorrect = FALSE,
    within = FALSE,
    **dist = NULL**,
    **squared = FALSE**, # false, otherwise it gets sqrooted! is this correct if using Euclidean dist?
    freq = TRUE,
    correction = NULL,
    sep = "_",
    filter = FALSE,
    threshold = 0,
    algorithm = "farthest_neighbor", 
    threads = 1L, 
    missing = "loci", 
    cutoff = 0.05,  
    quiet = FALSE, 
    method = c("pegas"), 
    nperm = 100000) 

Results:
Warning message:
In poppr::poppr.amova(myGenlgiht,  :  Missing data are not filtered from genlight data
Analysis of Molecular Variance
Call: pegas::amova(formula = hier, data = hierdf, nperm = nperm, is.squared = FALSE)
            SSD       MSD  df

clusters   1500.402 1500.4016   1
pop        3329.225  832.3063   4
Error    142431.371  847.8058 168
Total    147260.997  851.2196 173
Variance components:
        sigma2 P.value

clusters   8.63952  0.0000
pop       -0.53478  0.8762
Error    847.80578
Phi-statistics:
clusters.in.GLOBAL (Phi_CT)      pop.in.GLOBAL (Phi_ST)    pop.in.clusters (Phi_SC)
           0.0100939536                0.0094691422               -0.0006311825

Variance coefficients:
   a            b                c

28.98276 29.03448 77.33333
I would like to know the following:

is it correct to set "is.squared = FALSE"  if I am letting the function calculate the genetic distance with dist() - which computes the Euclidean distance?

why does the function tell me "warning: missing data are not filtered" even if I set the argument "missing = "loci" ", so that it should remove all loci for which there are missing information (only in each pairwise distances i think?)

is it correct that the sigma^2 for clusters = variation among clusters & sigma^2 for pop = variation among populations BUT within clusters?

what does the **Error **correspond to in my case? would that be the remaining variation - so variation among individuals BUT within populations or within the all sample (across all populations)?

If I use ade4 implementation in poppr::amova, I also obtain the % variance explained by each hierarchical level. How do I obtain that ifrom the pegas results?
Is it correct that to obtain the % variance for each hierarchical level --> i sum all sigma^2 values (cluster+pop+error) and then divide each by the sum?
i.e. % variance explained by clusters = sigma^2 for clusters/sum sigmas100
and
% variance due to variation among individuals = sigma^2 for error/sum sigmas100 ??

What do the coefficients a, b, c mean?
I understand that they represent the slope/effect of each treatment (in this case group/population/individuals) on the genotype...but how would you interpret them along with the variances?

Finally, I get opposite results (variation among populations more significant then among clusters) if I use ade4 (with same n permutation in randtest) --> any reason why? and which result to trust?


I would really appreciate some feedback and help interpreting these results!
Thanks!
Gabriella
I tried running popprr:amova with either the pegas and the  ade4 implementation and 3 hierarchical levels (clusters, populations, individuals). I set within individuals = false when using pegas because I understand that there is a bug in the within individual computation of variation for this package.
Running poppr::amova with ade4 implementation
my ade4 code and results are below for comparison:
Eucl_popprAMOVAres_ade4 = poppr::poppr.amova(
 myGenlight,
    hier = ~clusters/pop,
    clonecorrect = FALSE,
    within = FALSE,
    dist = NULL,
    squared = FALSE, # false, otherwise it gets sqrooted!
    freq = TRUE,
    correction = NULL,
    sep = "_",
    filter = FALSE,
    threshold = 0,
    algorithm = "farthest_neighbor", 
    threads = 1L, 
    missing = "loci", 
    cutoff = 0.05,  
    quiet = FALSE, 
    method = c("ade4"), 
    nperm = 100000) 

Warning message:
In poppr::poppr.amova(myGenlight,  :
Missing data are not filtered from genlight data
$call
ade4::amova(samples = xtab, distances = xdist, structures = xstruct)
$results
                                                         Df      Sum Sq  Mean Sq

Between clusters                                  1    984.7106 984.7106
Between samples Within clusters     4   3844.9162 961.2291
Within samples                                  168 142431.3705 847.8058
Total                                                     173 147260.9974 851.2196
$componentsofcovariance
                                                                                     Sigma               %

Variations  Between clusters                                           0.2675142   0.03139829
Variations  Between samples(*pops) Within clusters  3.9289742     0.46114598
Variations  Within samples (*pops)                             847.8057771  99.50745573
Total variations                                                              852.0022654 100.00000000
$statphi
                          Phi

Phi-samples-total    0.0049254427
Phi-samples-clusters 0.0046129082
Phi-clusters-total   0.0003139829
random test
Eucl_popprAMOVAres_ade4_amova.test = randtest( Eucl_popprAMOVAres_ade4, nrepet = 100000)

Eucl_popprAMOVAres_ade4_amova.test

class: krandtest lightkrandtest
Monte-Carlo tests
Call: randtest.amova(xtest = Scallop_Rep98_Loc95_Eucl_popprAMOVAres_ade4,
nrepet = 1e+05)
Number of tests:   3
Adjustment method for multiple comparisons:   none
Permutation number:   100000
Test         Obs    Std.Obs   Alter      Pvalue
1   Variations within samples 847.8057771 -9.8469609    less 9.99990e-06
2  Variations between samples   3.9289742  8.3893135 greater 9.99990e-06
3 Variations between clusters   0.2675142  0.1030489 greater 4.00706e-01
In ade4, the p-value of cluster is much larger than for pop, and pop is very significant. While in pegas: cluster is significant populations within clusters is not.
